# how to find even and odd numbers from any text file in java

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileEx
{
 public static void main(String ar[])
 {
     int i;
     try{
     FileInputStream fodd = new FileInputStream("dataodd.txt");
     FileOutputStream fin = new FileOutputStream("data.txt");
     FileInputStream feven = new FileInputStream("dataeven.txt");
    
     while((i=fin.read()) != -1) 
     {
      if(i%2==0)
      feven.write(i);
      else
      fodd.write(i);
     }
    
     fodd.close();
     fin.close();
     feven.close();
     }catch(Exception e){
        
     }
 }
}
```

I want to find even and odd number from any text file and store even numbers in one text file(i.e. dataeven.txt) and odd numbers in another file(i.e. dataodd.txt).
I have tried it to much times but i didn't find error,it shows error like "cannot find symbol" like below:

[image]
Program name is FileEx.java.
i am using 1.8.0_25 version of JDK and 1.8.0_45 version of JRE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileOutputStream` does not have a `read` method and `FileInputStream` does not have a `write` method.

You are simply messing up the streams here: you read from an `InputStream` and write to an `OutputStream`.